# Python lists similitudes

Tags: python, list

I am looking to get the number of similar characters between two lists. 
The first list is:

```
list1=['e', 'n', 'z', 'o', 'a']
```

The second list is going to be a word user inputted turned into a list:

```
word=input("Enter word")
word=list(word)
```

I'll run this function below to get the number of similitudes in the two lists:

```
def getSimilarItems(word,list1):
       counter = 0
       for i in list2:
           for j in list1:
               if i in j:
                   counter = counter + 1
       return counter
```

What I don't know how to do is how to get the number of similitudes for each item of the list(which is going to be either 0 or 1 as the word is going to be split into a list where an item is a character).

Help would be VERY appreciated :)

For example:
If the word inputted by the user is **afez**:
I'd like the run the function:

```
wordcount= getSimilarItems(word,list1)
```

And get this as an output:

```
>>>1 (because a from afez is in list ['e', 'n', 'z', 'o', 'a'])
>>>0 (because f from afez isn't in list ['e', 'n', 'z', 'o', 'a'])
>>>1 (because e from afez is in list ['e', 'n', 'z', 'o', 'a'])
>>>1 (because z from afez is in list ['e', 'n', 'z', 'o', 'a'])
```

Comment: Please add sample inputs / outputs to make clear what you are after

Comment: so the desired output is ... `[1,0,1,1]`?

Comment: yes, because I'd like to compare the lists ['a','f','e','z'] and ['e', 'n', 'z', 'o', 'a'], and a,e and z are in the second list so the output would be 1, and f isn't so the output would be 0

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you simply want:

```
def getSimilarItems(word,list1):
    return [int(letter in list1) for letter in word]
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't know how to do is how to get the number of similitudes
>   for each item of the list(which is going to be either 0 or 1 as the
>   word is going to be split into a list where an item is a character).

I assume that instead of counting the number of items in the list, you want to get the individual match result for each element.

For that you can use a dictionary or a list, and return that from your function.

Going off the assumption that the input is going to be the same length as the list,

```
def getSimilarItems(list1,list2):
     counter = 0
     list = []
     for i in list2:
          for j in list1:
              if i in j:
                  list.append(1)
              else:
                  list.append(0)
     return list
```

Based off your edit,

```
def getSimilarItems(list1,list2):
     counter = 0
     for i in list2:
         if i in list1:
             print('1 (because )'+i +' from temp_word is in list'+ str(list1))
         else:
             print("0 (because )"+i +" from temp_word isn't in list" + str(list1))
```

Look at Julien's answer if you want a more condensed version (I'm not very good with list comprehension)

Comment: you might as well condense it to this then: `def getSimilarItems(list1,list2): return [int(i in j) for i in list2 for j in list1]`